# Google App engine 32MB max request size limit- how to upload large files?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine

We've got a set up using google appengine with a docker container running a laravel application. Our users need to upload large video files (max 1028MB) to the server which in turn is stored in GCS. But GAE gives an error 413 Request entity too large nginx. I've confirmed this is not an issue on our server configs but a restriction on GAE
This is a pretty common requirement. How do you guys get around this?

What i've tried:

- Chunking using this package https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload and dropzone.js to break down the file when sending (Still results in 413)
- Blobstore API is not applicable for us as we need to constantly retrieved and play the files.

Comment: I believe that you can't change this limit on GAE. I think your only option is to upload the file from the user's computer directly to Google Cloud Storage and then process the file from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: @AjaxNash did you find a solution to this?

Comment: We can't change the size limit. What i did was upload directly to GCS and send a path reference to my backend server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @GAEfan, you can't change this limit on GAE. The recommended approach would be to upload your files to Google Cloud Storage and then process the file from Google Cloud Storage.